# How to resolve namespace clashes when including a module within a module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, namespaces, module, include

Here is what my code looks like:

```
module A
  def foo
    puts "A"
  end
end

module B
  include A
  def bar
    foo
  end
end

class MyClass
  include B
  def foo
    puts "X"
  end
  def self.test
    puts bar
  end
end
```

When I call "C.test" I get "X" instead of "A" (which is what I want) because the local definition of foo has overridden that in A. I can't change the signature of either foo's. I can only mainly edit my own class; I can edit modules A and B but lots of existing code use them and they are (so no changing foo to A.foo for instance). I am thinking of doing

```
class MyClass
  module MyModules
    include B
  end
  ....
    MyModules.bar
  ....
end
```

But this does not work.

How can I "localize" the namespace when doing include B?

Comment: Including `B` in `MyClass` means you want to add the methods `foo` and `bar` to `MyClass`.  Are you trying to include `B`'s `foo` only for some methods in `MyClass` but not others?

Comment: I think (1) that `C.test` should have read `MyClass.new.test`, and (2) that `MyClass.test` should not have been a class method, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for what I wanted, might not be the best answer but works exactly the way I want it to.

```
class MyClass
  class MyModules
    extend B
  end
  ....
    MyModules.bar
  ....
end
```

This effectively allows me to limit the scope of B and all other included modules in the local class MyModules. In my code it actually has a meaning because all the included modules handle expression manipulation so I can call the local class "Expr" (and they are seriously overusing the names 'eval', 'bind' and 'free' right now).

Comment: I think this is a useful pattern too. As a side note, be aware that the module will not have access to the instance, and that all instances will have access to the same module scope. But this is only relevant if the modules have state.

Answer (score 3):

From what i understand, you want to override `A#foo` (which is also used by `B#bar`) inside `MyClass`. However, you only want to override it inside `MyClass`, and not for the code in the `B` mixin.

The thing to understand here, is that when the code of the `A` and `B` mixins are run, they will be part of a `MyClass` instance. Therefore, it is impossible to override the instance methods of `MyClass` without affecting the mixins. It is as if the methods of the mixins were thrown into a bucket (the `MyClass` instance), and then run. They do not have separate scopes. Therefore, the simple answer is: no, you can not do it.

There could be several possible solutions though, many of which [smell like pasta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). Running into problems like this one could be an indication that the overall design decisions need some refactoring.

Going over the basics of modules:

```
module Numbered
  DEFAULT = "1234-AWESOME"
  def serial_number
    DEFAULT
  end
  def self.awesome?
    true
  end
end

Numbered.awesome? # => true
Numbered.serial_number # whoops! NoMethodError.

o = Object.new
o.extend(Numbered)
o.serial_number #=> "1234-AWESOME"

Numbered.extend(Numbered)
Numbered.serial_number # => "1234-AWESOME"

class Dog
  extend Numbered
end

Dog.serial_number # => "1234-AWESOME"
Dog::DEFAULT # => "1234-AWESOME"
fido = Dog.new
fido.serial_number # NoMethodError!
```

This is because the method was added as a class method. `include` to the rescue:

```
class Fish
  include Numbered

  def serial_number
    super + '-FSH'
  end
end

cod = Fish.new
cod.serial_number # => "1234-AWESOME-FSH"
```

So, `include` heaps all the methods together into one common instance, but we can still use `super` to call an included method that we were overriding. If you go for a solution on the pasta side, you might be able to use super inside the `bar` method, conditionally invoking the method you were overriding.

Also, depending on the case, you could set up a new module and `extend` it with the module containing the methods you need access too, like in the answer you added.

Comment: That didn't really help me but it was very informative. Thanks!